# What is the teaching-lab tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Simple question. What is the [teaching-lab](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-lab) tag for? Should it be applied to questions regarding general lab procedure or does it (as the name suggests) have something to do with teaching? Most of the questions which have the tag are just about general procedure but this doesn't seem to fit with the name of the tag. Maybe someone can do a tag wiki for it.

As a secondary question, if [teaching-lab](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-lab) is specifically about teaching then should we have a tag for general lab work such as `lab procedure` or something similar? [experimental-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-chemistry) is already a closely related tag but it seems to be more broad than a tag specifically about practical technique.

Comment: Well, if there's anything to come outta this, it's that I don't pay attention to tags very well. ;) Seriously though, this tag baffles me. Some questions even don't need it. We might need the burninating unilateral metal fist of Manish in near future.

Comment: I think that [Safe explosion demonstrations](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16122/safe-explosion-demonstrations) is a good example of proper use of this tag. It's about experiments in a lab focused on demonstrations and teaching, rather than on research. From the 17 questions with the tag though, it seems to be the only one actually needing it.

Comment: I think the biggest problem with the semi-meta tags is, that they can be applied to almost everything. It also get much harder, when there is not even a well defined tag wiki behind it (like in that case). I always thought the tag was meant to be applied, when special pedagogic concepts are applied/requested and or a specific audience (elementary, secondary school, etc.) is targeted. I would currently not go as far as quenching it from the system, but I think we need this discussion to form a scope when this tag should be applied.